# Different output between du and ls -h on mongodb .wt file

Tags: mongodb

```
$ du -sh 0--989303831270119069.wt 
1.6T    0--989303831270119069.wt

$ ll -h 0--989303831270119069.wt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongo mongo 3.6T Oct 22 18:17 0--989303831270119069.wt
```

I want to know why? Is it a sparse file or something else?

Comment: Database files are very often sparse,  so that's a good bet.

Comment: but I think ls -h and du -sh ,these two commands should be the same output... like Mysql

Comment: No, not with sparse files. ls gives length (that is, highest byte written to), but du gives storage consumed.

Comment: WiredTiger does not use sparse files, so the effect you're seeing is uncommon. Something to do with your filesystem perhaps? How are you mounting MongoDB's data directory?